# Undefined private variables

Tags: php, warnings

I get:

> Undefined variable: password
>   Undefined variable: host
>   Undefined variable: user

I am just curious why I am getting such notices,
although the variable has been defined in the private section of the class.

Can't I use private data member of the class in the member function (because that would defeat the whole concept of OOP)?

The php file is:

```
class data_base //helps handling permissins
    {
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;

    public function feed_data($hst, $usr, $pwd)
        {
            $host=$hst;
            $user=$usr;
            $password=$pwd;
        }
    public function get_data()
        {
            $info=array("host"=>" ", "user"=>" ", "password"=>" ");
            $info['host']=$host;
            $info['user']=$user;
            $info['password']=$password;    
            return $info;
        }
      }

   $user1=new data_base; 
   $user2=new data_base;

   $user1->feed_data("localhost", "root", ""); //enter details for user 1 here
   $user2->feed_data("", "", ""); //enter details for user 2 here

   $perm_add=$user1->get_data();
   $perm_view=$user2->get_data();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP you must call a property as a property

```
$this->host;
// instead of
$host;
```

Unlike for example in java `$host` is *always* a local variable and thus undefined here.

As a sidenote: You can write

```
$info=array("host"=>" ", "user"=>" ", "password"=>" ");
$info['host']=$host;
$info['user']=$user;
$info['password']=$password;    
return $info;
```

as

```
return array(
    'host'     => $this->host,
    'user'     => $this->user,
    'password' => $this->password
);
```

It's short and imo more reable (No need for a temporary variable)

Comment: In that particular case even just: `return get_object_vars($this);`.

Comment: @hakre Yes. But I for myself don't like it, because it may accidentally expose more than wanted, when the class gets extended later. I like the more verbose way :)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, to access instance variables, you need to use `$this->varname`.
Just `$varname` is always a variable local to the method.